# Is there a way to make CSS (and browser) use system's version of a font if it exists, otherwise font-face?

Tags: html, css, fonts, webfonts

I only want to use a font (and have the browser download it) if the OS the browser is on doesn't have that font built in. Is this possible?

Currently, I define the font with `@font-face` but this causes the broswer to download the font automatically. I only want that to happen if that font is not already on the system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the `@font-face`, specify a `local` source, e.g.

```css
@font-face {
    font-family: Open Sans;
    src: local('Open Sans'), url('../fonts/open-sans.woff') format('woff');
}
```

Note that users may have broken local fonts.

Comment: what do you mean by broken local fonts? is this common? any way to detect it?

Comment: @DonRhummy: It’s not too common, but it has happened to me once (with Google Fonts’s Fira Sans). There’s no way to detect it.